# Razr mouse on Macbook Pro lost middle click functionality after installing new firmware

Tags: laptop, mouse, macbook-pro

I started using the Razor Deathadder mouse on my new Macbook Pro today. The middle button was working until I downloaded the latest firmware for the mouse. Now it won't work anymore. I was using the mouse on a PC before. How can I get this feature back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using SteerMouse for a year or so now. It's a $20 utility to allow for better external mouse configuration.

http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/

In addition to allowing very specific button configurations, it also provides specific movement customization which lets me specifiy a more Windows-like acceleration curve. Mice under OSX's default control feel sluggish to me and SteerMouse straightens that behavior right out.

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. I installed this app, but now I have a bigger problem. The trackpad lost its gentle tap functionality. I want to occasionally use trackpad too! Do you happen to know how I can remove the preferences SteerMouse added to my computer? I already dropped it in the trash can, but that didn't help.

Comment: Hmm, SteerMouse doesn't affect the trackpad -- only external mice.

You removed the preference pane item to the Trash? If you reinstall it, I think there's an option to uninstall it from inside the application.